# Is there a way to configure magento to bcc an email in every mail send out on a forgot password attempt?

Tags: email, password-recovery

I need to send a copy of the forgot password email to a particular email address every time on forgot password attempts. Is there way to configure this in magento ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be bad practice to do this as passwords are meant to be secure. However if you insist on following this through, you would have a few approaches.

**Mail Server Configuration**

Some mail servers can be configured to handle this from their configuration. This of course assumes that you have server administrator rights to the mail service.

**Magento Customisations**

If you follow the customer account forgot password controller path, you will be lead to the method sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail() within the customer model, Mage_Customer_Model_Customer. If you override this you can customise the logic that will be sent out including adding your own BCC header.

Comment: thanks so as its a bad practice can we be sure that magento will not provide a configuration for doing this ?

Comment: BTW we are not sending password but password reset links

Answer (score 1):

if you see the function `sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()` in `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` class you will find the following code

```
$this->_sendEmailTemplate(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            array('customer' => $this), $storeId);
```

so try to override _sendEmailTemplate() function of the same class i.e Mage_Customer_Model_Customer

and add following code in it

```
protected function _sendEmailTemplate($template, $sender, $templateParams = array(), $storeId = null)
        {
            /** @var $mailer Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer */
            $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
            $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
            $emailInfo->addTo($this->getEmail(), $this->getName());

            if($template == 'customer/password/forgot_email_template'){
                /* email ids */
                $bcc = array("emailid1@some.com","emailid2@some.com");
                $emailInfo->addBcc($bcc);
                /* email ids */ 
            }
            $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);

            // Set all required params and send emails
            $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig($sender, $storeId));
            $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
            $mailer->setTemplateId(Mage::getStoreConfig($template, $storeId));
            $mailer->setTemplateParams($templateParams);
            $mailer->send();
            return $this;
        }
```

Edited:- Now i added a conditon `if($template == 'customer/password/forgot_email_template'){}` which will only send mail to bcc if the request is forgotpassword.

Note:- but this is bad because you will get passwords in your email of your customers